# Image locating with pyautogui

Tags: pyautogui

With pyautogui I'm trying to locate a object in a screenshot that is being taken but I can't find a way

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con

time.sleep(2)
ims = pica = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(569,381,800,450))
iml = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(1040,295,100,30))
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

#Color of center: (255, 219, 195)

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    flag = 0
    pyautogui.screenshot(region=(1040,295,100,30))
    ims.save(r"C:\Users\Billy Bong\Desktop\python\saveimage.png")
    pica = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(569,381,800,450))
    ims.save(r"C:\Users\Billy Bong\Desktop\python\saveimage2.png")
    time.sleep (2)

    pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen("saveimage.png", confidence=0.6)
    print (cords)
    pyautogui.click (cords)
    time.sleep (10)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **minimal code** for locating an object on the screen, you should have the image of the object.

```
import pyautogui as py
import keyboard

while True:
    img = py.locateOnScreen("object.png", confidence=0.9) # add path to your object image here

    print(img)

    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

there is something i found out about pyautogui if u gonna use locateonscreen or locateallonscreen the image u asking him to locate must be in same folder u running the script from (according to my experience from using VS-code) and idk if there is a way to tell it to set a path for the image u wanna search to (something) so for the current time make sure u include all images u search for in same folder that the script is running from for me it is (E:\coding\game) cuz i make auto bots for games i like

btw locateallonscreenn prints out a list, the "cords" but idk if "pyautogui.click (cords)
" understand that and if it is going to click all the x,y in cords or not